# Changing Color of Web.config Name Attribute Value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, colors, web-config

I cannot seem to find where to change the color of value for the name attribute in the web.config.  By default it's a dark blue which makes it hard to read using themes like Son of Obsidion and Code Anxiety.  I changed the color for "XML Keyword" which I thought it was but the color still does not change.

Example:

```
<behavior name="Default">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
</behavior>
```

In this case the color of the value "Default" stays dark blue.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20):

If you have VSCommands installed then it's VSCommands.Xml.KeyAttribute in Fonts and Colors settings.

This is done by Highlight Key Attributes feature which highlights attributes such as name, id, guid and key. You can disable it completely from Tools | VSCommands | Options | Text Editor | Xml

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this in a native way but this also works.

Answer (score 0):

Use **XML Name** property in the Fonts and Colors list.